# Add bootstrap icons next to fields in node page

Tags: 7

In my views I can do this easily using the rewrite results and writing this line

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone list-icon"></span>  [field_business_phone]
```

How can I do the same with the node page. It doesn't necessarily have to be a rewrite method but I am looking for an easy method of doing this. The end result I am looking for is something like this.
[image: Views fields with icons]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the preprocess function, like:

```
function YOUR_THEME_preprocess_field(&$variables) {
  $element = $variables['element'];

  if (isset($element['#field_name'])) {
    if($element['#field_name'] == 'field_business_phone') {
      foreach ($variables['items'] as $k => $value) {
        $variables['items'][$k]['#markup'] = '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone list-icon"></span>' . $variables['items'][$k]['#markup'];
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Or overwrite the field templates, in a file named **field--field-business-phone.tpl.php**, containing something like:

```
<?php

<div class="<?php print $classes; ?>"<?php print $attributes; ?>>
  <?php if (!$label_hidden): ?>
    <div class="field-label"<?php print $title_attributes; ?>><?php print $label ?>:&nbsp;</div>
  <?php endif; ?>
  <div class="field__items"<?php print $content_attributes; ?>>
    <?php foreach ($items as $delta => $item): ?>
      <div class="field__item <?php print $delta % 2 ? 'odd' : 'even'; ?>"<?php print $item_attributes[$delta]; ?>><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone list-icon"></span> <?php print render($item); ?></div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well...simple as that I guess...I can't understand most of the code provided due to my lack of php and drupal api knowledge...but it did the trick. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I did actually but I don't have enough reputation I guess.

Comment: A strange thing is happening I use the code below to show the icons but the website field doesn't show it. I double checked the name of the field and cleared the caches. Do you have any clues why this is happening and how I can troubleshoot?
`if($element['#field_name'] == 'field_business_website') {
      foreach ($variables['items'] as $k => $value) {
        $variables['items'][$k]['#markup'] = '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-link list-icon"></span>' . $variables['items'][$k]['#markup'];
      }
    }`

Comment: See if the code get's hit. place a `drupal_set_message('hit: ' . $element['#field_name']);` just before the if statement, and you should see all field names from all fields that get preprocessed.

Comment: Strangely it does get hit. `hit: field_business_website` . No markup (span) is added though.

Comment: And the field has content (items) ?? Or is it empty ?!

Comment: Is not empty that is sure. In this way it does have content (items) right?

Comment: Ok, so debug further and log the values inside the if and the for loop ..